# How do I create a workflow that lets me know when someone has completed my Survey in SharePoint 2016?

Tags: sharepoint-server, workflow, 2016, survey, nintex

I'm fairly new to SharePoint. I created a Survey in SharePoint 2016 and my boss wants to be notified when someone completes the survey. I have been looking for answers with no luck. I did learn that (correct me if I am wrong) you can not associate a workflow with a Survey in SharePoint 2016.

I would have to link a custom list to the Survey but I have no idea how to do that.

I tried creating a custom list and I created columns each with a name of all of the Survey questions. But no luck linking this list to the Survey.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you create the survey using SharePoint default "Survey" list template?

Comment: I went into Site Contents > Add an app > Searched for Survey and chose the Survey option.

Comment: Ok, check my answer given below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get notified when someone completed the Survey, you can use the SharePoint default **Alert Me** functionality instead of creating a new workflow from scratch.

Follow the steps:

1. Go to SharePoint Site Contents page
2. Open your Survey list
3. Click on Actions --> Alert Me

   [image]
4. Add your and manager name in "Send Alerts to" field. Set other alert options as per your requirements and click "OK" button to save changes:

   [image]

Comment: Thank you, I didn't realize that you could send alerts to others aside from myself like this. But, I would still like to know if a Workflow is a possibility? And is linking a list to a Survey possible as well?

Comment: Yes, you can create a SharePoint designer workflow for survey lists as well like any other lists. You don't need to create any other list and link survey list to another list.

Comment: Ok thank you, I don't think I will need to do that. These alerts should be good enough.

Comment: You're welcome, glad it helped you!